# ExceptionTranslationFilter Unable to handle the Spring Security Exception because the response is already committed

Tags: spring-security

I want to throw AuthenticationException when BasicAuthenticationFilter authentication fails and handle it uniformly, returning json.

But ExceptionTranslationFilter not work.

In ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter() it will check that the response.isCommitted() and throw "Unable to handle the Spring Security Exception because the response is already committed".

So this is normal? How do I unify the handling of these AuthenticationExceptions?

dependencies : spring-security:6.1.5.

SecurityFilterChain:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
return httpSecurity
        .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .sessionManagement(sessionManagement ->
                sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager(), objectMapper, whitelist))
        .addFilterAfter(new DecryptRequestFilter(), JWTAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(new ExceptionTranslationFilter(unauthorizedEntryPoint), JWTAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .build();
}
```

doFilterInternal() in JWTAuthenticationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter :

```java
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String path = request.getRequestURI();
    AntPathMatcher antPathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();
    if (whitelist.getWhitelist().stream().anyMatch(s -> antPathMatcher.match(s, path))) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    String token = request.getHeader(ConstantKey.HEADER_TOKEN_KEY);
    if(StringUtils.isEmpty(token)) {
        throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("token not found");
    }
    String subject = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(ConstantKey.TOKEN_SIGN_KEY)
            .parseClaimsJws(token)
            .getBody()
            .getSubject();
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(subject)) {
        throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("token is invalid");
    }
    AuthSubject authSubject;
    try {
        authSubject = objectMapper.readValue(subject, AuthSubject.class);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException("read auth subject error", e);
    }
    Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> simpleGrantedAuthorities = authSubject.getRoles().stream()
            .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authSubject.getUsername(), null, simpleGrantedAuthorities);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
    request.setAttribute(AuthSubject.Fields.username, authSubject.getUsername());
    request.setAttribute(AuthSubject.Fields.roles, authSubject.getUserId());
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

commence() in UnauthorizedEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint:

```java
@Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
    response.setContentType(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
    response.getWriter().write(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(
            GenericRestResponse.builder()
                    .status(YesOrNo.NO.getCode())
                    .message(authException.getMessage())
                    .build()
            )
    );
}
```

I tried to use AuthenticationFailureHandler but still can't catch the AuthenticationException.

Comment: the problem here is that you shouldn't be having a JWTFilter at all. Handing out tokens JWTs to browsers has been deprecated in the oauth2 standard, and the authentication method is not recommended for browser client. Thats why there is no such implementation in spring security, so the question is more why are you building a custom deprecated, unseccure home made security solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used [Spring Authorization Server](https://spring.io/projects/spring-authorization-server) to implement the oauth2 authentication server.

Reference [youlai-mall](https://github.com/youlaitech/youlai-mall/tree/master/youlai-auth) project to implement the password authentication method.